# How to share geolocation tags in photo streams?

Tags: sharing, photos.app

I have made over 3000 pictures during my last trip, mostly with the iPhone.

I then shared them as a photo album in iCloud with my family, but neither of us can figure out how to enable geolocation data. It obviously would be quite handy to know which picture is taken where, and display the map like photos can for unshared pictures.

How is that done?

Comment: Similar question (iCloud Photo Sharing rather than Photo Streams): [How can location data be retained when using iCloud Photo Sharing?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/305490/19025)

Comment: @EdwardBrey Well, iCloud Photo Sharing comes much later than Photo Streams ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under Preferences, select "Include location information for published items". You then probably need to delete and re-create your shared album to get the location metadata

Comment: Thanks! It's a bit frustrating that the setting be global... I might want to share locations with my gf, but not with my colleague. Maybe I'll file a request on Apple's bug report tool ^^ Also, having to recreate the album would suck,  already have lots of comments on it. I'll see if it updates by itself.

Comment: You may be able to delete and re-add the pictures and comments attached to the album will remain.

Comment: Which preferences are you referring to please?