# How can location data be retained when using iCloud Photo Sharing?

Tags: icloud, photos.app

Everyone in my household has an iPhone and is running iOS 11. We have a shared album that we can post to, but whenever one of shares a photo, the location data isn't included.

Is there a way we can fix this? I love the location feature of macOS Photos, and have gone back and added it to scans of snapshots from before digital cameras. If someone shares a photo in the family album, I'd like to include that data.